# different types of exceptions in .net

Tags: .net, exception

What is the purpose of having so many types of exceptions in .net?  Why not just use Exception?

Some of them are EndOfStreamException, FileLoadException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, InvalidTimeZoneException......

Comment: I think the names of these exception classes makes the answer quite obvious... How would you know what kind of error happened if there was only Exception ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The individual exception types allow more information about the exception, and what caused it, to be passed.

For example, a [FileNotFoundException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filenotfoundexception.aspx) tells you exactly why you received the exception, and lets you look at properties of the exception like which filename caused the failure, etc.

WIth a general "Exception" class, you'd only know "something went wrong", but not what specifically went wrong.  By using concrete types, you have more flexibility to handle the exception and recover gracefully.

Answer (score 1):

Because you might want to catch one of them.  You can't selectively catch an exception if they are all raised as Exception.